# Addon that automatizes firefox browsing

Tags: firefox, internet

I am looking for an addon that will makenbrowser actions automatized - for example it will fill one form with some data many times and in each iteration there will be an increment in one of form's fields. After each form submit result page will be saved.

Any addon like this around? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two extensions to suggest:

- [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/downthemall/)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 2):

One more: [iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/)

> Automate Firefox. Record and replay repetitious work. If you love the Firefox web browser, but are tired of repetitive tasks like visiting the same sites every days, filling out forms, and remembering passwords, then iMacros for Firefox is the solution you’ve been dreaming of!
>
> *Whatever you do with Firefox, iMacros can automate it.*
>
> [image]